# Difference between emberjs and jqueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, scalability, frontend

So far as I know emberjs is a front end framework while jQuery UI is also a front end framework. I wonder which one to use is a better option for building a scalable app's front end since jQueryUI seem will have better compatiblities than Emberjs as it developed by the same developers (I suppose).

Please compare the two and their similarities and differences. Also, why use one while not to use the other? Or its better to integrate both together and why?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember and JQueryUi really solve two very different problems.  JQueryUI is strictly focused on providing UI components that could be use in any web app.  Ember is is focused on allowing you to build single page applications in predictable/repeatable way.  It's pretty common to use Ember as the main project framework with JQueryUI also used to provide UI widgets for some portions of the app.